# Is it safe to have a mysql server on a home computer?

Tags: mysql

I installed a mysql server 5.7 in my home computer but I am afraid if someone scans my ip with nmap then he will simply find open mysql port no. 3306 as windows service and then he can simply bruteforce to gain access if I have a weaker password.
So, using a complex password will be enough? What else configuration can i do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do hope your Windows system is not accessible from the Internet, as in, there is no firewall between your Windows system and the open Internet.

You can configure either or both mysql and Windows Firewall to only allow connections from certain networks or computers. It depends a lot on what other systems use this mysql server, if there are any ... if the only system using the mysql database is your home computer it is installed on, then you can limit connections to loopback (localhost, `127.0.0.1`) and you should be so much safer.